# Console app for calculating circumference of various shapes defined by user input

Tags: java

I had an assignment to create a circumference calculator in Java which I've already submitted. I would like feedback on my code.

The program works as intended, but I am not sure whether it's spaghetti code or not after realizing that I only called one method in main which calls all of the other methods. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class circ
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
     mainMenu();


  }//end main method

//----------------------- Main Menu --------------------------------//
  public static void mainMenu()
  {
     String shape = "";

     //while loop to repeat program 
     while (!shape.equals("q"))
     {

        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\tCircumference Calculator \n");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t--------Main Menu--------\n");
        System.out.println("Square(1) \t\t Rectangle(2) \t\t Triangle(3) \t\t (Q)uit");

        shape = menuInput().toLowerCase();      //call menu input method, parse to lower case so that user can input Q or q to quit

        switch(shape.charAt(0))
        {
           case '1': 
              squareInput();
              break;

           case '2':
              rectInput();
              break;

           case '3': 
              trInput();
              break;

           case 'q': 
              System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
              break;

           default: 
              System.out.println("\n\n\t\tInvalid input! Please select 1, 2, 3, or Q\n\n");
              break;       
        }//end switch

   }//end while loop

  }//end main menu method

  // ------------- general input method for shapes -------------//
  public static double input()
  {
     Scanner KB = new Scanner(System.in);
     double value;
     value = KB.nextDouble();

     if(value < 0)
        value = validation(value);

     return value;
  }//end input method

  // -------------------------- input method for the main menu -----------------------//
  public static String menuInput()
  {
     Scanner KB = new Scanner(System.in);
     String choice = " ";

     choice = KB.nextLine();
     return choice;


  }//end menu input

//--------------------------------shape input methods--------------------------------------------------------//   
  public static void squareInput()
  {
     double side, circ = 0.0;
     System.out.println("Side: ");
     side = input();

     circ = squareCirc(side);

     squareOutput(side, circ);

  }//end square input

  public static void rectInput()
  {
     double length, width, circ = 0.0;

     System.out.println("Length: ");
     length = input();

     System.out.println("Width: ");
     width = input();

     circ = rectCirc(length, width);

     rectOutput(length, width, circ);


  }//end rectangle input method

  public static void trInput()
  {
     double side1, side2, side3, circ = 0.0;

     System.out.println("Side 1: ");
     side1 = input();

     System.out.println("Side 2: ");
     side2 = input();

     System.out.println("Side 3: ");
     side3 = input();

     circ = triCirc(side1,side2,side3);

     triOutput(side1,side2,side3, circ);
  }//end trInput()

//----------------------------- shape process methods ------------------//
  public static double squareCirc(double x)
  {
     return(4 * x);
  }

  public static double rectCirc(double x, double y)
  {
     return(( 2 * x) + (2 * y));

  }

  public static double triCirc(double x, double y, double z)
  {
     return(x + y + z);

  }

//----------------------output methods---------------------------//
  public static double squareOutput(double x, double circ)
  {
     System.out.println("Square: \n");
     System.out.println("Side = " + x);
     System.out.println("Circumference = " + circ);

     return 0;
  }//end square output

  public static double rectOutput(double x, double y, double circ)
  {
     System.out.println("Rectangle: \n");
     System.out.println("Length = " + x);
     System.out.println("Width = " + y);
     System.out.println("Circumference = " + circ);

     return 0;
  }//end rectangle output

  public static double triOutput(double x, double y, double z, double circ)
  {
     System.out.println("Triangle: \n");
     System.out.println("Side 1 = " + x + " Side 2 = " + y + " Side 3 = " + z);
     System.out.println("Circumference = " + circ);

     return 0;
  } //end triangle output

//------------------------input validation method --------------------//
  public static double validation(double x)
  {
     Scanner KB = new Scanner(System.in);

     while( x < 0)
     {
        System.out.println("\nValue must be greater than 0!\n");
        x = KB.nextDouble();

     }//end loop

     return x;

 }//end method

}//end class
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not spaghetti code. Although it is a bit strange that main just calls mainMenu. It could contain a loop that would end when mainMenu returns false and mainMenu would return false if user wants to quit.

There are a few minor gotchas, im sure someone else will point out...

I just wanna say this Is a good candidate for OOP, especialy for Its polymorphism feature. But I suppose you're not that far yet, so I won't show you any code, unless you're really interested.

It's quite a good code for the level I suppose you are on :)

One note, there is hardly any value in those comments, use comments to clarify things that may not be obvious. Commenting on block ends and repeating what is clear from code itself just does not help, if not worse. And honestly i dont see a single useful comment in your code. It is just too simple to need any.

Maybe one more, dont abbreviate names like `trInput`, it then starts to need comments... Code that is self documented is always better (in terms of readability) then having to explain everything in comments.

It may be good to comment on complex formulae as to why they solve given problem as those things are often not clear at first glance, you may put a reference to mathematical proof in comment for example. Or if a function accepts integer, but it wont work if it is larger than 100, then put it in comment with explanation why it cannot work. And things like that...

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I'll try writing another version with the loop you mentioned. And I'll admit, I have no idea what polymorphism is yet, but I wouldn't mind seeing some examples. I'm in my first year of college and OOP has just started to click for me recently

Comment: @shaggy Oh, In that case, I wouldn't recommend trying out implementing some polymorphism yet. You need some basics about classes first. I'll just say that polymorphism is feature that allow you to implement similar behaviour, yet different, in a way that one implementation is substituable by another one. In your case, it would be 3 classes (square, rectngle and triangle), all implementing the same interface (ie. shape) which would allow it to 1) load from user input 2) compute circumference 3) output its state into console. This allows to easily add more shapes in future.